# Rails foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm not sure if I fully wrap my mind around this. I want to create a relationship between `stores` and `documents`.

In the document table I want a reference to the `store` and `account` that created it. To do this would I  run this migration

```
rails g AddStoreToDocuments store:references
```

and then in the model, specify `foreign_key`s of `account_id` and `store_id`?

like this?

```
has_many :stores, foreign_key: "store_id"
```

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to read [rails guide on migration.](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

You can generate the reference by using

```
rails g migration AddStoreRefToDocuments store:references
rake db:migrate
```

This will generate the migration. Your models should have association mentioned to make it work

```
Class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents
end

Class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> In the document table I want a reference to the `store` and `account`
>   that created it.

Your relationship should be `belongs_to` instead of `has_many`:

```
belongs_to :store
belongs_to :account
```

Notice that, since you are following ActiveRecord conventions, you don't need to specify any foreign key (it will use `store_id` and `account_id`).

And `has_many` relationship should be used in both `Store` and `Account` models:

```
has_many :documents
```

You will also need to update your migration (or create a new one) to add `account:references`.

Answer (score 1):

Your documents table should have reference to both tables.

```
rails g AddStoreToDocuments store:references account:references
```

relation should be store has_many documents and account has_many documents.
So in Document model :

```
belongs_to :store
belongs_to :account
```

in Store model :

```
has_many :documents
```

in Account model :

```
has_many :documents
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly, your migration would throw an error, it should be

```
rails g migration AddStoreToDocuments store:references
```

generated migration looks like

```
def change
  add_reference :documents, :store, index: true, foreign_key: true
end
```

then do,

```
rake db:migrate
```

which will automatically create a column `store_id` in your `documents` table, so in your `documents.rb`

```
belongs_to :store
belongs_to :account #this you might already be having I suppose
```